# Create a Date class with fields day, month and year. (You cannot use the built-in DateTime class from .NET Library)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create properties corresponding to these fields, but I'm having trouble making the logic for setting the correct day,month and year without using the DateTime class.

So the user will enter the data one at a time: Day, Month and Year in that order.

And the day should be between 1 and 30 or 31 or 28 -  based on the month. Month must be between 1 and 12 and the Year must be less than or equal to 2013

Then I need to make a test case that will take the 3 values of day, month, and year and make an instance of date.

Then I have to create a Sentinel controlled loop to ask the user to enter the day, month and year and create an instance the Date with the user input using the constructor. and Terminate the program if the user enters 0 for the day, month or year.

I am mostly having trouble getting the logic down.

```
public class Date
{
   public int Month { get; set; }

   public int Day { get; set; }
   public int Year { get; set; }

   public Date ( int monthValue, int dayValue, int yearValue)
   {
       Month = monthValue;
       Day = dayValue;
       Year = yearValue;
   }
   public int theMonth
   {
       get {return Month;} 

       set
       {
           if (value <= 12) Month = value;

       }

    }
   public int theDay
   {
       get { return theDay; }
       set
       {
           if (value <= 30) Day = value;
           else if (value == 31) Day = value;
           else if (value == 28) Day = value;
       }
   }


   public override string ToString()
   {
        return String.Format( "{0}/{1}/{2}", Month, Day, Year);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `DateTime` class?

Comment: It's a school assignment, which logic parts are confusing you?

Comment: My professor does not want us to use it. but I am having trouble with coming up with the if statement needed to set the correct day month and year.

Comment: The .NET Framework guidelines say that properties should be settable in any order.  This is problematic with a Day and Month setters.  Therefore I'd make a class (or struct) with readonly properties and only do the requested validation in the constructor.

Comment: But WHAT is your problem? In your theDay property, you have to take into account the month...

Comment: im trying to write logic that will determine the day month and year without using the dateTime class.. the code above is just something I was playing with because i have no idea how to go about writing this logic and know it is not correct and does not make sense.. I am just really stuck right now.

Comment: Guys I think this is a really elementary assignment and he just needs a date that fits his very general requirements.

Comment: yeah pretty much... I'm  not the best coder but i understand the concepts but when it comes to the logic I just cant seem to come up with what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array with the month (0-11) and the corresponding days in each.
For Febrary, you place the most common one (28) but if entered a 29 for febrary... you need to check if the year is a leap year.

To determine whether a year is a leap year, follow these steps:

> 1.If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
>
> 2.If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
>
> 3.If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
>
> 4.The year is a leap year (it has 366 days).
>
> 5.The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).

The above procedure can be summarized in:

```
if(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0){
  return true; // it is leap year
}
else{
return false; //it is not leap
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but I'm not required to calculate the leap year just the regular stuff. I just posted my code above.. I'm having trouble with the if statement part..

Comment: @user2487144: The point of calculating the leap year is figuring out if February can have 28 days or 29. If somebody entered `29,2,2013` it would be invalid. But `29,2,2016` is valid.

Comment: Oh okay I understand what you mean now.

Comment: "To determine whether a year is a leap year" - or you could call `DateTime.IsLeapYear(int year)`

Comment: Actually the summarized code would say that the year 2004 is not a leap year which is incorrect. The real logic for leap year can be seen here: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-check-leap-year

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your own class myDateTime that has ints Day, Month, Year.

Then you'll want to make a while(userinput != 0) loop where your program begins.  When you receive input, you'll want to validate each integer, and then, if the data is valid, create an instance of myDateTime with the values.

An example for data validation:

```
if(userInputDay >= 1 && userInputDay <= 31 )
    myDateTime.Day = userInputDay;
```

From your code:

```
if (value <= 30) Day = value;
else if (value == 31) Day = value;
else if (value == 28) Day = value;
```

Is the same logic as:

```
if(value <= 31) Day = value;
```

Here's a start for you, it's pretty dumb and doesn't do any error checking but it's a start

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input Month, Day, Year separated by spaces");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (input != "0")
        {
            String[] nums = input.Split(' ');

            int month = Convert.ToInt32(nums[0]);
            int day = Convert.ToInt32(nums[1]);
            int year = Convert.ToInt32(nums[2]);

            if (month > 0 && month <= 12 &&
                day > 0 && day <= 31 &&
                year <= 2013)
            {
                //valid
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Input Month, Day, Year separated by spaces");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


}

class myDateTime
{
    public int Day;
    public int Month;
    public int Year;

    public myDateTime(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        Month = m;
        Day = d;
        Year = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just put in the code i have so far and i know it is not correct but this is what i have been playing with since im not sure how the logic goes..

Comment: well you never use theMonth or theDay

Comment: so would I go about doing it like your example i guess? because I'm really lost on what do write to make it set the correct month,day, and year.

Answer (score 0):

So you might want to start with a container which to hold the date components. You had a pretty good start with your `Date` class, but I would submit you don't want those values mutating once set. One method to accomplish this by using a simple immutable `struct`:

```
public struct MyDateTime
{
    private readonly int year;

    private readonly byte month;

    private readonly byte day;

    public MyDateTime(int year, byte month, byte day)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get
        {
            return this.year;
        }
    }

    public byte Month
    {
        get
        {
            return this.month;
        }
    }

    public byte Day
    {
        get
        {
            return this.day;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can begin to add validation logic to the constructor to meet your constraints:

```
public MyDateTime(int year, byte month, byte day)
{
    if ((year < 0) || (year > 2013))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", year, "year must be greater than or equal to zero and less than 2013.");
    }

    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("month", month, "month must be between 1 and 12, inclusive.");
    }

    if (/* leaving the days based on month (and perhaps leap year) calculation up to YOU! */)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("month", month, "month must be between 1 and 12, inclusive.");
    }

    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
}
```

Your calling code can catch the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and notify the user of the invalid input.

Further enhancements might include using an `enum` to represent the valid month values rather than a numeric. Depends on your needs.

Comment: how would i go about writing a test case for this class where the user enters the day month and year and if they are not 0 they get put into an instance of MyDateTIme and are printed out to the console.